# Erlang - Searching for tuples within tuples

Tags: erlang, tuples

Using Erlang, I have the following expression:

```
{add,{var,a},{mul,{num,2},{var,b}}}
```

and I am using lists:keymember to see whether the letter b is within the expression as such:

```
lists:keymember(b,2,[expr])
```

However, it doesn't look within the third tuple '{mul,{num,2},{var,b}' as that is a separate tuple. Is there a function that will search through the whole tuple and tuples within?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far I as I know there are no such functions. Probably you will have to implement some custom solution using recursion. Here is my example:

```
-module(test).
-compile(export_all).

find(_, []) -> false;

find(E, T) when is_tuple(T) ->
    find(E, tuple_to_list(T));

find(E, [H|T]) ->
    case find(E, H) of
        false -> find(E, T);
        true -> true
    end;

find(V, E) -> V == E.
```

And usage:

```
1> test:find(b, {add,{var,a},{mul,{num,2},{var,b}}}).
true
2> test:find(b, {add,{var,a},{mul,{num,2},{var,c}}}).
false
```

Comment: Can't you just use `lists:any/2` instead of your own `find/2`? Also, as @fenollp said, the question is about a tuple - I don't think `|` works on tuples.

Comment: Thanks, I went for something like this in the end!

Answer (score 2):

Please review your code.

- Line1: this is a tree, not a list.
- Line2: `expr` is not a variable.

What you want to do is a visitor function, and you'll have to write it yourself.
A very good start would be to [read this](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-exceptions#try-a-try-in-a-tree).